# Spot the mistake on disproving uniform convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

It is known that the function $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$ has the Taylor expansion $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$.

> I want to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$ does not converge uniformly to $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$ on the open disk $|z|<1$.
>
> I use the negation of the definition of uniform convergence.

Let $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2}$.  $\forall N\in \mathbb{N}$, let $n = N$ and $z= 0$ .

Then $|z^n-\dfrac{1}{1-z}| = |0^N - \dfrac{1}{1-0}| = 1 > \dfrac{1}{2}$

Hence, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$ does not converge uniformly to $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$ on the open disk $|z|<1$.

> But i noticed that there is something wrong in my proof since it also work for any closed subdisk in the open disk $|z|<1$, which contradicts the Taylor theorem that states that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$ converges uniformly to $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$ on any closed subdisk contained in the open unit disk centered at $0$.

Where did i make a mistake in the proof for not uniform convergence?

Answer (score 0):

What you must study here is the difference between $\sum_{n=0}^Nz^n$ and $\frac1{1-z}$. That difference is$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^Nz^n-\frac1{1-z}\right|=\frac{|z|^{N+1}}{|1-z|}.$$If $z\in[0,1)$, this is just $\frac{z^{N+1}}{1-z}$ and, since $\lim_{z\to1^-}\frac{z^{N+1}}{1-z}=+\infty$, this is greater than $\frac12$ if $z$ is close enough to $1$.

Comment: @LittleRookie What does that mean?

Comment: Can you give an example of $z$ and show that $\frac{|z|^{N+1}}{|1-z|} \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @LittleRookie Sure. Take $z=\sqrt[N+1]{\frac34}$. Then $4z^{N+1}=3$ and this implies that $4z^{N+1}+3z>3$. But the inequality $4z^{N+1}+3z>3$ is equivalent to $\frac{z^{N+1}}{1-z}=\frac34$ and $\frac34>\frac12$. Note that, since $z\in[0,1)$, $\frac{z^{N+1}}{1-z}=\frac{|z|^{N+1}}{|1-z|}$.

Comment: @LittleRookie Was my answer helpful?

Comment: I just noticed that it is much simplier to prove that the series is not Cauchy, i.e. the sequence of partial sum is not Cauchy for |z|=1, hence diverges on |z|=1.

Comment: @LittleRookie How do you deduce from that that the convergence is not uniform on the disk $|z|<1$?

Comment: I should be clearer, i meant that for the case of the Circle of convergence $|z|=1$ (Not the disk of convergence $|z|<1$ as stated in the original post) , it is easier to prove that the series is not Cauchy than other methods. So i'm thinking if i can do the same for the case of disk of convergence $|z|<1$.

Comment: @LittleRookie In the circle $|z|=1$, the series diverges, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}z^n\neq0$. That's all. I don't see how do you intend to apply the same idea in order to prove that the series does not converge uniformly on the open disk $D_1(0)$.

Comment: I see. I think it is easy to see that $\lim_{n\to \infty} z^n \neq 0$ for points with |z|=1. But in an exam (i'm a student), it is not sufficient to only state that $\lim_{n\to \infty} z^n \neq 0$ because anyone could state that without understanding. For the points $1,-1,i,-i$, proving $\lim_{n\to \infty} z^n \neq 0$ is easy. But not for the other points on the circle of convergence.

Comment: So, i choose to prove that the series is not Cauchy for points on the circle $|z|=1$ because it is easier. I can see that the last line of the proof would be $|z^{N+1}| = 1 > \epsilon$ (Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: @LittleRookie $|z|=1\implies|z|^n=1\iff|z^n|=1$. So the distance from *each* term of the sequence $(z^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ to $0$ is equal to $1$. Therefore, the sequence $(z^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Yes, i agree that this is intuitive since raising $z$ to any positive integer power does not change the distance of $z$ from $0$. But i'm not sure if it is enough to write this for an exam. But i could also prove it by showing that the series is not Cauchy for each point on circle $|z|=1$ right?

Comment: @LittleRookie What I provided has nothing to do with intuition. It is a *proof* of the fact that the sequence $(z^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge to $0$, from which one deduces that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The uniform limit of bounded functions is bounded. Each partial sum of $\sum z^n$ is bounded on the open unit disc. However the pointwise limit function, $1/(1-z),$ is not bounded there. Hence the convergence cannot be uniform on the open unit disc.